# Get file length for Black Berry Dynamics in objective-c

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, blackberry

How do i get the file content size in the Blackberry dynamics SDK using GDFileManager or GDFileStat.

Comment: I know nothing about the BlackBerry Dynamics SDK, but first Google result leads to [`fileLen`](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/files/blackberry-dynamics/ios/struct_g_d_file_stat.html#ab73bf6b44df9d502fc6e1f3257c307b6) with a deprecation note leading to [`attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/files/blackberry-dynamics/ios/interface_g_d_file_manager.html#a22a6ceef74ce9109805a24b28ed671f5) & [`NSFileSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilesize?language=objc).

Answer (score 1):

In general, Dynamics SDK APIs are similar to the Native SDK APIs.

https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/files/blackberry-dynamics/ios/interface_g_d_file_manager.html#a22a6ceef74ce9109805a24b28ed671f5

This API should give you the file size.